# Update Keycloak's ID Token

Tags: jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

When a user logs in (through Keycloak, with OpenID Connect using the authorization code flow), Keycloak creates an [ID token](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect#id-token) and stores it as a JWT in a cookie.

Now, let's suppose while the user is already logged in, he/she changes some data like his/her phone number which also happens to be stored in the ID token.
This data is changed outside Keycloak and eventually changed in Keycloak's database. After this update is performed, if the user logs out and logs in again, the ID token is updated with the new data (a phone number in this particular case).

**Now, is there a way to update the ID token with the new data, without requiring to logout and login again?**

Thank you very much for your help!

I have tried reading the documentation but couldn't find anything for this **exact** purpose/requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to log out to get a new ID token. You can just run the authorization code flow once more and you should get a new ID token with updated values. Another thing is that you somehow need to know that you should run the flow again.

If you want to make sure that you have fresh info about the user, you can call the userinfo endpoint whenever you need that data. This way you're sure that you always get the fresh data straight from Keycloak.